# How to cite (Author, Year) in with linked DOI in bibliography in LyX

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing, natbib, doi

I am trying to write my thesis in LyX and want to achieve the following:

My citations should appear as `(Doe, 2005)` as an inline citation, I also need to be able to cite without parenthesis, as in `"According to Doe et al. (2005), ..."`

At the same time, I want the bibliography to contain a hyperlinked `DOI`, but not the `URL`, if present in the `.bib` entry. I don't care too much about how exactly the rest bibliography looks like, as long as it's complete.

I don't think that this is a particulary strange need, I generate my `.bib` files via Mendeley, so sometimes I have some weird and extremely long links in the `.bib` that would clutter up a nicely formated bibliography. Having a clickable `DOI` seems to be fairly obvious need to me, as most documents are nowadays circulated as pdfs.

So far I had only limited success: The `.bst` style files I could find are not Natbib compliant and produce numbered inline citations only. Or, I am getting everything wrong and don't understand how to properly set the style of the inline citation... thanks for help.

Comment: I believe that LyX uses (or can use) BibTeX, but probably not BibLaTeX. You will have to use the correct profile (i.e. one that uses BibTeX) and chose a suitable citation style. The `natbib` package is most suitable for author-year citations as you want them. With `natbib`, `\citet{KEY}` produces "Author (year)" and `\citep{KEY}` produces "(Author, year)". You will have to find a suitable `\bibliographystyle{}` to fit your needs, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using natbib to get my inline citations to look corrrect. However, I can't use styles like [this](https://github.com/higham/njhigham-bib) or [this](http://ctan.mackichan.com/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/unsrturl.bst) because the compiler complains: _Check the bibliography entries for non-compliant syntax,
or select author-year BibTeX style, e.g. plainnat_. I don't want to use plainnat obviously, and my `.bib` is mendeley autogenerated and looks fine. I found an answer that a missing year entry can cause this error too, but all my entries have years and authors.

Comment: I do not know why exatctly you get that error, but both .bst files are obviously numeric citation styles, not suitable to produce what you want anyways. If you do not want to use plainnat, look for another style in the author-year format (e.g. `apalike`), or create your own using makebst.

Comment: I was looking for another style but couldn't find one. Thank you for mentioning makebst, I didn't know that program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it to work. Here is a not really good solution, in case another LyX user stumbles over this.

1. Choose Natbib as citation style in the `Bibliography` pane in the document settings
2. add `round` to `Custom Class Options` at the `Document Class` pane in the document settings. While this makes no sense to me, this option (!) is forwarded to Natbib.
3. add `\usepackage{doi}` to your preamble
4. I took plainnat as a template and removed all lines that included `url` except the last 4 (all in the function `begin.bib`)

did a similar thing with [apalike-refs](https://github.com/matthieu-vergne/LaTeX/blob/master/apalike-refs.bst) removing the ISBN and ISSN functions. Works and looks a bit better ...